# WSGI with python eve [Errno 32] Broken pipe... Ajax call

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, wsgi, eve

I'm running a simple wsgi server,

```
from run import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(threaded=True, debug=True)
```

And I am hitting the server with a get request, the server returns a 200 message, but doesn't return any data. I get the following error message

```
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 209, in run_wsgi
execute(self.server.app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 200, in execute
write(data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 175, in write
self.send_header('Server', self.version_string())
 File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 401, in send_header
self.wfile.write("%s: %s\r\n" % (keyword, value))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I've read in a few places that using the threaded option should get round a broken pipe error, but hasn't seemed to help in my case. Does anyone have any ideas?

Flask version is 0.12.2.

!!!EDIT!!!

So the point of the page I'm developing is to take user defined coordinates from a leaflet map and make a call to a database, in this case neo4j. The query works fine, as does the API as it all works well in postman. So the problem must be somewhere in my web app. Here is my server app for the web page. Maybe in the Ajax call?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
@app.route('/demo')
def webMap():
    return render_template('demo3.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8090)
```

Here is the JS:

```
var map = L.map('map1').setView([51.506725, -0.076486], 12);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: '*************************'
}).addTo(map);


//add start marker to map and delete old marker
var startmarker = null;

map.on('click', function (e) {
    if (startmarker !== null) {
        map.removeLayer(startmarker);
    }
     startmarker = L.marker(e.latlng, {
         title: "Start Point",
     }).addTo(map);
    startcoords = e.latlng.lng.toString() + "&" + e.latlng.lat.toString();
    startmarker.bindPopup("Start " + startcoords);
});


//add end marker to map and delete old marker

var endmarker = null;
map.on('contextmenu', function (e) {
    if (endmarker !== null) {
        map.removeLayer(endmarker);
    }
     endmarker = L.marker(e.latlng, {
         title: "End Point",
     }).addTo(map);
    endcoords = e.latlng.lng.toString() + "&" + e.latlng.lat.toString();
    endmarker.bindPopup("End " + endcoords);
    coords = startcoords+"&"+endcoords;
});

// choose query type, click button & Ajax call to API server

$("#button").click(function() {
    var val = $('input[name=query]:checked').val()
    if (val == 'route') {
        stuff = $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/route&"+coords,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json" ,      
        })
        .done(function( json ) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(stuff));  // trying to JSON back will work out how to display it after I get some data returned 
        })
        .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
            alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!");
            console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
            console.log( "Status: " + status );
            console.dir( xhr );
        })
        .always(function( xhr, status ) {
            alert( "The request is complete!" );
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The Broken pipe indicates that the other end of a socket or pipe that your flask process wants to talk to has died. Considering that you are interacting with the database it's very likely that the database has terminated the connection, or the connection has died for other reasons" ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34976901/323269))

Comment: Thanks Nicola, but the same query works when sent through postman, maybe the problem lies in either the Ajax call I'm making? I will edit above with more details